# The return type is incompatible with

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, three.js, lwjgl

#### Background

I am writing a three.js for java and using LWJGL as a backend. I am extending LWJGL with the required methods that three.js needs but I have run into a problem.

#### The problem

I need to Override Vector2f.set and so on for each of its libraries because I simply need those methods to return themselves to behave like three.js. I have tried the following to do so:

```
@Override
public Vector2 set(float x, float y){
    super.set(x,y);
    return this;
}
```

Eclipse complains that the two methods are not compatible. Are you allowed to Override void returns, and if not should I just create a seperate method name for this call? Is there a way to completely override the superclass method and ignore it?

Comment: If you Override a method, it needs to have the same signature.

Comment: a non void setter doesn't make sense anyway, but I believe in your case you can't override because of the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override void methods, but you must override them with another void method.  The return types and parameter types of overriding methods need to be compatible with their overridden methods.

If you have an option to do so, I suggest that you use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a vector - a vector is slower because it synchronizes all of its methods, which is usually overkill.

Comment: It's actually pretty neat that subclasses are allowed to return subtypes of return values for overridden methods.

Comment: @jontejj As long as the contract is not broken, no problem.

Comment: If you're keen to follow the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) all subtypes must follow the contracts specified by their parent classes

Answer (score 1):

If you want chaining, you probably need

```
public Vector2 modify(float x, float y) {
    set(x, y);
    return this;
}
```

It's hard to emulate code in other languages perfectly.